# How to show that if an $m$ by $n$ matrix has trivial null space, then $m \ge n$?

Tags: linear-algebra

How to show that if an $m$ by $n$ matrix has trivial null space, then $m \ge n$? Should I use dimension theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: recall that a matrix $A \in \mathbb{k}^{m \times n}$ represents a linear transformation from $\mathbb{k}^n$ to $\mathbb{k}^m$ via $f(x) :=Ax$. What can you say about $\ker f$?

Solution:

> We have that $\ker f = \{x : f(x) = 0\} = \{x : Ax = 0\}$, so $A$ having trivial nullspace implies $\ker f = \{0\}$. By the dimension theorem, $n = \dim \mathbb{k}^n = \dim(\ker f) + \dim(\operatorname{im} f) = \dim(\operatorname{im} f)$. Since $\operatorname{im} f \leq \mathbb{k}^m$, we get $\dim(\operatorname{im} f) \leq \dim(\mathbb{k}^m) = m$ which concludes the proof.

Comment: Why do you say $\operatorname{im} f \leq \mathbb{k}^m$ instead of $\operatorname{im} f \subseteq \mathbb{k}^m$?

Comment: @user398843 $S \leq T$ is notation for '$S$ is a subspace of $T$'. It certainly implies $S \subseteq T$.